# Analytic maps from upper half plane to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I know that the bilinear map $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, ad-bc>0$, maps the upper half plane onto itself. But is every analytic function that does so is of this form?

Comment: Did you mean $ad-bc>0$? Consider $f(z) = -z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the correctness of the sign in the question, the answer is no, meaning that there are analytic functions from the upper half plane onto itself which are not Möbius transformations.
See for instance [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/332948/90588) or the book [The Problem of Moments](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-1) by Shohat and Tamarkin.

Comment: while the linked answer is nice, it is overkill imho - here the result follows easily by using the standard Mobius transform to the unit disc and the corresponding result there (result which is an easy corollary of Schwarz lemma)

Comment: That's true. If we're merely concerned about their existence rather than their description, equivalence between disk and upper half plane via Möbius transformations gives us a family of very obvious candidates $(z^n)$.